# Removing specific strings from file

Tags: command-line

I have a file containing some data as in the following example:

```
data1: it is my data
data2: some more data
data3: even some more data
```

What I want is the following output in another file:

```
it is my data
some more data
even some more data
```

Please guide me how to do it!

Comment: should be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jobin why it should be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: This is not specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: you didn't see any bash scripting commands before in AU?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -i .bak 's/[^:]*: *//' file
```

**Explanation:** The `-i .bak` will edit the file in place, and create a backup of the original called `filename.bak`. `s/pat/replacement/` means substitute `pat` with `replacement`. `[^:]*: *` means match the longest string of non-`:` characters, followed by a `:` then one or more space. The final result is that it will delete everything up to the first `:` and following spaces.

This approach has the advantage of working with `data:` or `foo:` or whatever and will also work if you have multiple `:` on the same line. For example, it can deal with this:

```
data: a line that contains : a colon!
```

Answer (score 8):

It's very simple if you use `awk`:

```
awk -F ': ' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' file_name > new_file_name
```

Each line is separated in more fields using `': '` as separator and print everything except the first field. The output is redirected to the `new_file_name`.

Comment: @Aditya he set the delimeter as : and awk considers the words before : as column 1 and the remaining part as column 2.After that the words from the column 2 are writed inside new_file.

Comment: @Radu am i correct?

Comment: @Aditya note that this will not work if your lines can contain more than one `:`. If that is possible use my solution below.

Comment: @terdon Now will work ;)

Comment: @terdon: I am not the OP. I had left the comment to explain because a command without any explanation looks dirty :-)

Comment: Radu, indeed, I would upvote you but I'm afraid I already have :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a job for `cut`

```
cut -d: -f2- file > new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/[^:]*: *//|x' file
```

1. `%` search all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in `vim` editor as follows:

`vi <filename>`

and then press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then the following:

```
:%s/data.: //gc
```

Here `%s` is used for string replace

`/` is the delimiter between the command and the strings

`data.:` is the first string, `.` is used for any single character
`gc` is used to find and confirm before replacing

Comment: please tell me a link where I could learn stuff about vi editors since it looks very promising.

Comment: @khan: Google is the best thing I could think of. May be you could start off [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your input file looks like an output of a grep command, say:

```
grep data data*
```

If this is really the case, you can use the -h option of grep command itself to get what you need:

```
grep -h data data*
```